# KDE 4.14 on OpenSuse, KDE Thunderbird with "Send as Email attachment"

Tags: kde, opensuse, thunderbird, kde4, servicemenu

I am running KDE OpenSuse 13.2 which has KDE 4.14. I could not find any way to configure the "Send as Email Attachment" service menu action to open Thunderbird through any standard configuration GUI. At present, this service menu opens kmail.

All searches on google pointed to old instructions that do not seem to work on OpenSuse 13.2.

What is the best practice to manage KDE's Service Menu's on OpenSuse 13.2?

Comment: Would be great to have a more user friendly way rather than hacking the ServiceMenu .desktop files.

Comment: For those interested, here is information on the ServiceMenu files: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Creating_Konqueror_Service_Menus

Answer (score 1):

I will share my hack to get it working on OpenSuse 13.2 with KDE 4.14.

**1. Edit the Service Menu**:

```
su -c 'vi /usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/kmail_addattachmentservicemenu.desktop'
```

**2. Comment out line:**

```
#Exec=kmail --attach %F
```

**3. Add the following line:**

```
Exec=thunderbird -compose "attachment='file://%F'"
```

**4. Save the file**.

You may need to restart Dolphin to see changes.